# Delete an app completely (special case) and question regarding empty trash

Tags: launchpad, trash, macos

I downloaded a game and deleted it by just Holding it for few second and click x on the launchpad, because I can still see it occupies 20 GB in my hard disk which is truly annoying. Does it mean it wasn't removed completely?

It seems the Mac can empty the trash securely or not securely? 
Does it mean whatever deleted in the trash (even you empty the trash) is possible to recover? Unless you press the Empty trash securely?
Thanks 
I feel like I'm so stupid, because I lost 40 GB by just doing deleting and downloading .... BUT I wouldn't lose any disk space if it 's microsoft window... this makes me feel really uncomfortable.. SSD is already very limited disk...

HOW can I get it back and delete it completely ? Is there any apps allow me to do so?  THANKS
N.B.I'm currently using the newest model of Mac book pro.

Situation: I deleted the file (by just holding it for few second and press the cross) but it still occupied 20 GB... Is there any way to get the space back?

Comment: Personally, I think if you download something you no longer find it useful and it still occupies space is ridiculous... That is like I can't download and try 10 different games.. because everytime i delete them they gonna take up my disk space ... for a huge proportion

Comment: Did you empty the Trash after pressing the X to remove the application? Which specific application are you talking about?

Comment: The absolute delete is the "rm" command in terminal. "rm filename.ext" will destroy the file and there is no recovery possible.

Comment: @Patrix No, unfortunately after I delete the apps, using the hold button, there's nothing in the trash.

Comment: Buscar, Now my problem is I deleted the "link" to access the game , but the stuff is still there occupying my disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use Clean My Mac for uninstalling software, it use 35mb of storage and its very useful because it delete all the info and stuff of the program, with this you`ll avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: same for your apps , thanks , but not that helpful in this scenario

Answer (score 2):

All the apps installed from the App Store are stored in the `/Applications` folder.
Go to the Applications folder (`Finder menu -> Go -> Applications` or check the Finder window sidebar for this folder), check if the app you want to delete is present there. If it isn't, then it's gone. Else, move it to Trash and then empty it.

If it doesn't help, please clarify how are you determining that 20GB is still occupied by the app.